# Android: Run FirebaseAnalytics logEvent with multithreading

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, firebase-analytics

Do we need to run "logEvent" methods in the background thread or it’s already implemented underhood?

Comment: By my knowledge firebase analytics run in background thread by default. but with the new profiler in android studio you can confirm that. Anyway you can use a coroutine to make the calls.

Answer (score 1):

logEvent does not have any requirements for threading.  It doesn't block the calling thread.  You can use it on the main thread with no problems.

Comment: I want to run the logging with multithreading to reduce loading

Comment: There's no need to do that.  Just call logEvent when you want to log an event.  It is not more complicated than that.  If you're observing something that suggests some optimization is required, then edit the question to explain in more detail what's wrong.

Comment: @DougStevenson see main answer: it can block the main thread

Answer (score 0):

I got the following ANR while using logEvent from the main thread:

```
com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdt.<init> (zzdt.java:1)
com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdr.<init> (zzdr.java:1)
com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzee.zzT (zzee.java:1)
com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzee.zzx (zzee.java:1)
com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.logEvent (FirebaseAnalytics.java:1)
```

so something is missing in the implementation and must be compensated on the caller side.

Comment: You should file a bug report with your findings, including the version of the SDK, the version of Play services, and your code.  It really shouldn't do this.  The API is definitely intended for use on the main thread, otherwise it becomes very difficult to use.  There's no reason why it couldn't queue up any possible blocking internally.

Comment: I agree with you, but also think that the team already reads ANR and Exceptions from developers console and is aware of this. More, most of the time, opening a bug is a waste of time because the support team responds after a long time (years) or often does not respond at all. It's better to spend time finding a solution for yourself

Comment: Sure, do what you need to do. But the cost of filing it is small, and if enough people file, they will definitely do something eventually.  Trust me, I used to work on Firebase at Google, and these sort of reports are taken seriously.  They just compete other things.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply, really appreciated. Unfortunately I don't trust in some G teams anymore, so I look for solutions here on Stackoverflow where the issues are really considered. Cheers

Comment: If you don't trust Google, then I'm curious why you are choosing to use their software!  It's better for everyone if you just take a moment to file it.  Nothing bad can happen. Keep using your own solution in case it never gets fixed.

Comment: To feed your curiosity: cause no alternatives at the moment. Regards